# Set material of instances on Geometry Nodes

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes

I'm using blender 3 for geometry nodes, I'm instancing cubes.

[image]

How do I add a material to them? The material of the parent object does not seem to transfer to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a "set material" node some time after they have been instanced